# Subir y conectarse a una base de datos desde JavaFX

Tags: mysql, javafx

Actualmente he concluido el desarrollo de una aplicación de escritorio en JavaFx y MySQL, la cuál solo se conecta a una base de datos localmente. ¿Habrá alguna forma de "subir" la base de datos a internet y conectarse a la misma base de datos desde mi aplicación de escritorio? ¿Es posible conectarse al mismo tiempo, desde varias computadoras hacia la misma base de datos una vez "subida" a internet?

Comment: La respuesta a tu pregunta es *`Sí, todo lo que preguntas es posible`*. Pero, en contextos como el que describes, lo que se suele hacer actualmente es programar una API o Servicio Web en el servidor donde está la base de datos y acceder a ella por medio de puntos de entrada. Por ejemplo, para traer los datos del usuario con `id=7`, el punto de entrada sería: `https://example.com/user/7`, para traer una lista de usuarios: `https://example.com/user/list`, para traer los datos de la ciudad con id 3: `https://example.com/city/3`, etc.

Comment: La ventaja de hacerlo así es que tu aplicación de escritorio podría instalarse en cualquier cliente sin ninguna configuración previa, mientras que si debes gestionar la conexión remota desde cada cliente todo se complica. Otro punto importante es **la seguridad de la base de datos**, permitir conexiones remotas sin control sería peligroso, por tanto tendrás que autorizar las direcciones IP de cada cliente, o rangos de IP (si los clientes no tienen IPs fijas eso será harto complicado), o bien configurar túneles de conexión usando llaves privadas/públicas, etc y configurarlo en cada cliente.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!, me aclaraste varias dudas, ¿No tendrías algún ejemplo de como hacer estos puntos de entrada? No tengo mucho conocimiento en lo relacionado a la web, pero actualmente estuve buscando un hosting y encontré **namecheap**, el panel de control que utiliza es cPanel, hay una opción en donde se puede conectar a una base de datos remotamente, ¿Esto se refiere a conectarse a una base de datos que este subida en este hosting desde cualquier computador con acceso a internet?

Comment: Correcto. La idea es la siguiente: necesitarás un dominio (`tudominio.com`)  el cual estará alojado en un hosting, el cual te ofrece poder alojar aparte del dominio una base de datos y te permite programar en su servidor con cualquier lenguaje de servidor (el más usado es PHP). Entonces, en PHP (u otro lenguaje de servidor) tendrás que programar la API o Servicio Web, de modo que cuando reciba algo como esto: `www.tudominio.com/user/1`, determine que estás pidiendo un `user`, y que el id de ese `user` es `1`. Partiendo de ahí, consulta a la BD, busca ese `user`  y lo devuelve al cliente ...

Comment: ... (se entiende por *cliente*  tu aplicacón JavaFX, esté donde esté). Entonces el *cliente* consumirá esos datos (los usará para mostrarlos o para operar con ellos). Las técnicas y herramientas para programar WebService o API son varias, tendrás que decidirte por una, cuando tengas el dominio montado y la BD creada. Puedes empezar por algo sencillo para probar, como una URL cualquiera que te mande un JSON y lo consumes en Java. El lado negativo aquí (que no es negativo realmente), es que tendrás que adentrarte en un mundo nuevo (la programación web), teniendo q aprender otro lenguaje (PHP ...

Comment: ... o el que decidas) y aprender algo sobre como funciona el alojamiento, algo de `.htaccess`, redirecciones, seguridad, etc, pero a la larga esta es una gran ventaja, porque te abre a una forma mejor de montar tus aplicaciones y aprender otro lenguaje te ayuda a refinar tus conocimientos sobre los lenguajes que ya conoces. Al final tienes a mano un conjunto de herramientas y conocimientos que te sirven para resolver cualquier tipo de problema o programar cualquier tipo de aplicación moderna.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta, me ha ayudado mucho, me di cuenta que es indispensable saber y conocer todo lo relacionado a desarrollo web, reitero, muchísimas gracias!